# What is the best way to access DbContext inside a Dialog class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, botframework

I have defined my DbContext in the `Startup.cs`

```cs
services.AddDbContext<GretaDBContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

I want to access the DbContext in my Dialogs in order to Add and Modify the entities in my database. The problem is my Dialogs are a Singleton service while the DbContext is Scoped so i can't DI it through the constructor.

I've read somewhere I should create a Controller obtaining the DbContext through the `IServiceProvider` and call Controller functions from the Dialogs but I don't know how to accomplish that.

What is the best way to be able to use the DbContext inside the Dialogs?

Comment: Why didn't you register the dialogs as transient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can request a scoped service within a singleton by creating scope and then retrieving the service from an `IServiceProvider` that is injected into the singleton:

```cs
public class DialogsSingleton
{
  private readonly IServiceProvider services;

  public DialogsSingleton(IServiceProvider services)
  {
    this.services = services;
  }

  public void DomeSomethingRequiringDbContext()
  {
    using (var scope = this.services.CreateScope())
    {
      var scopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<GretaDBContext>();
      // Use the scoped service
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see how that would work for me. But would I have to do this every time I want to add a new item in the dbcontext, or every time I want to iterate through items, etc.?

Comment: @FerranCapalleraGuirado That is hard to answer without specific knowledge about what kinds of operation have to be performed at what point in time. It's obviously not required to create a new scope and retrieve a new DbContext for every single operation you want to perform on the database, but you also do not want a DbContext to hang around forever. What you probably need is to get an idea about what operations belong together, and then wrap these within one scope using the same DbContext. E.g. iterating through several items and then changing one of them would probably make a good scope.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. That solves my question for now, I'll mark up your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a business logic layer(BLL). You can inject your DbContext into this layer. From there you should be able to inject you BLL into a controller and have your Dialogs reach out. Your controller typically shouldn't contain logic. You may be able to access your BLL from within your dialogs rather than a separate controller.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I would gladly appreciate if you could write an example with some code, to see how the classes would link to each other.